# How we create stsURI for athentication in Azure

Tags: azure

I want to push Message in the queue using Azure Service Bus
I go through with lots of solutions but I found most of them are done by using Connection string of the Service Bus with SharedAccessKeyName and Value
but I want to achieve the same using sts uri
I tried with Get-SBClientConfiguration command also on power-shell to get stsuri
How we get stsuri for azure service bus authentication

Comment: Hmm, the only way of authentication for Azure SB that I know of is Shared Access Signatures, which uses those keys. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-authentication-and-authorization

Comment: OK , can you please tell me how we create stsUris for service bus in below link they explain about same but I ma unable to get the same 

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9380861c-13cf-4a4f-90e7-93d4ae3158b8/wcfclient-and-wcfservice-with-service-bus-unauthorizedexception?forum=servbus